# How would I find the cosines of angles between a three dimensional vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the angles $\alpha ,\beta ,\theta $ between the vector $(1,0,-1)$ and the unit vectors $i,j,k$ along the axes?

This question is not making sense to me. I know that in order to find the angle between any two nonzero vectors, I just have to take their dot product and divide it by the product of their lengths as such: $\cos { \theta  } =\frac { \overrightarrow { v } \cdot \overrightarrow { w }  }{ \left\| v \right\| \left\| w \right\|  } $

How can I extend this knowledge to the 3 dimensional vector I was given? I don't know how I can get the dot product of the given vector with the given unit vectors.

Hints only, please. No actual solution.

Comment: Just use the formula.  It works for any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $i=(1,0,0)$, $j=(0,1,0)$, $k=(0,0,1)$. Or equally, $$ (1,0,-1) = i-k $$.

Answer (score 0):

For example, we have
$$
(1,0,-1)\cdot \hat i = (1,0,-1) \cdot (1,0,0) = 
(1)(1) + (0)(0) + (-1)(0) = 1
$$